# Why does dashboard navigation pattern doesn't have 2nd/3rd level menu?

Tags: usability, navigation, menu

As I've noticed on some dashboard navigation pattern like [Pure](http://purecss.io/) and[Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), they don't have 2nd/3rd level menu.

What is the reason why does that type of menu doesn't have 2nd level? If I'm going to impose a 2nd/3rd level menu does it considered as bad UX?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you want to facilitate things to the user. A 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> level navigation is similar to a mega menu: it used to be good, but only make things hard and boring to the user. See [an article about outdated UX patterns](http://sideproject.io/outdated-ux-patterns/) for more information on it.

I think what you should aim here is to draw your user's flow. How they will interact with your website and how they can get to the most relevant content with the least effort. You shouldn't depend on multi level navigations. Instead, show the user the most important things, create paths that leads them from one place to the other and let them navigate and find the things they want.

The user is impatient and like to get to where they want quickly.